# Объединить (склеить по вертикали) две Excel таблицы при помощи Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть первая таблица excel

```
  Подразделение   № Информация            Дата Акта  Сумма Акта  \
0            ПИИ   1       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
1            ПИИ   2       Факт  25.07.2018 11:18:07    295000.0   
2            ПИИ   3       Факт   01.08.2018 0:00:00    920671.0   
3            ПИИ   4       Факт  09.08.2018 14:44:12    401200.0   
4            ПИИ   5       Факт  21.08.2018 23:59:59    188800.0   
5            ПИИ   6       Факт  21.08.2018 23:59:59    354000.0   
6            ПИИ   7       Факт  17.09.2018 23:59:59   1613985.0   
7            ПИИ   8       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
8            ПИИ   9       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
9            ПИИ  10       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
10           ПИИ  11       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
11           ПИИ  13       План                  NaN         NaN   
12           ПИИ  14       План                  NaN         NaN   
13           ПИИ  15       План                  NaN         NaN   
14           ПИИ  16       План                  NaN         NaN   
15           ПИИ  17       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00    991200.0   
16           ПИИ  18       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00    354000.0   
17           ПИИ  19       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00    188800.0   
18           ПИИ  20       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00   2534656.0   
19           ПИИ  21       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    350000.0   
20           ПИИ  22       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    719800.0   
21           ПИИ  23       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   3300000.0   
22           ПИИ  24       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   1534000.0   
23           ПИИ  25       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   3894000.0   
24           ПИИ  26       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    241000.0   
25           ПИИ  27       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    590000.0   
26           ПИИ  27       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   1475000.0
```

Прочитала значение из неё:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 120
df_b = pd.read_excel(r'АнализПодр.xlsx', sheet_name="Данные", skiprows=1)
```

Есть вторая таблица:

```
                  Дата    Сумма                  \
0  25.07.2018 11:18:07   295000     
1   01.08.2018 0:00:00   920671      
2  09.08.2018 14:44:12   401200     
3  21.08.2018 23:59:59   188800             
4  21.08.2018 23:59:59   354000          
5  17.09.2018 23:59:59  1613985     
6                Всего  3773656
```

Прочитала:

```
df_a = pd.read_excel(r'Пример выгрузки из 1С.xlsx', sheet_name="акты", skiprows=3)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно дописать ниже данные из второй таблицы в соответствующие столбцы из первой("Дата Акта", "Сумма Акта"). Заранее благодарна за ответ

Должно получиться:

```
  Подразделение   № Информация            Дата Акта  Сумма Акта  \
0            ПИИ   1       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
1            ПИИ   2       Факт  25.07.2018 11:18:07    295000.0   
2            ПИИ   3       Факт   01.08.2018 0:00:00    920671.0   
3            ПИИ   4       Факт  09.08.2018 14:44:12    401200.0   
4            ПИИ   5       Факт  21.08.2018 23:59:59    188800.0   
5            ПИИ   6       Факт  21.08.2018 23:59:59    354000.0   
6            ПИИ   7       Факт  17.09.2018 23:59:59   1613985.0   
7            ПИИ   8       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
8            ПИИ   9       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
9            ПИИ  10       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
10           ПИИ  11       Факт                  NaN         NaN   
11           ПИИ  13       План                  NaN         NaN   
12           ПИИ  14       План                  NaN         NaN   
13           ПИИ  15       План                  NaN         NaN   
14           ПИИ  16       План                  NaN         NaN   
15           ПИИ  17       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00    991200.0   
16           ПИИ  18       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00    354000.0   
17           ПИИ  19       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00    188800.0   
18           ПИИ  20       План  2018-09-01 00:00:00   2534656.0   
19           ПИИ  21       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    350000.0   
20           ПИИ  22       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    719800.0   
21           ПИИ  23       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   3300000.0   
22           ПИИ  24       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   1534000.0   
23           ПИИ  25       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   3894000.0   
24           ПИИ  26       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    241000.0   
25           ПИИ  27       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    590000.0   
26           ПИИ  27       План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   1475000.0
                                 25.07.2018 11:18:07   295000     
                                 01.08.2018 0:00:00    920671      
                                 09.08.2018 14:44:12   401200     
                                 21.08.2018 23:59:59   188800             
                                 21.08.2018 23:59:59   354000          
                                 17.09.2018 23:59:59  1613985
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [pandas.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'Дата':'Дата Акта','Сумма':'Сумма Акта'})],
                ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

результат:

```
In [22]: res
Out[22]:
   Подразделение № Информация            Дата Акта  Сумма Акта
0          ПИИ 1         Факт                  NaN         NaN
1          ПИИ 2         Факт  25.07.2018 11:18:07    295000.0
2          ПИИ 3         Факт   01.08.2018 0:00:00    920671.0
3          ПИИ 4         Факт  09.08.2018 14:44:12    401200.0
4          ПИИ 5         Факт  21.08.2018 23:59:59    188800.0
5          ПИИ 6         Факт  21.08.2018 23:59:59    354000.0
6          ПИИ 7         Факт  17.09.2018 23:59:59   1613985.0
7          ПИИ 8         Факт                  NaN         NaN
8          ПИИ 9         Факт                  NaN         NaN
9         ПИИ 10         Факт                  NaN         NaN
..           ...          ...                  ...         ...
24        ПИИ 26         План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    241000.0
25        ПИИ 27         План  2018-12-01 00:00:00    590000.0
26        ПИИ 27         План  2018-12-01 00:00:00   1475000.0
27           NaN          NaN  25.07.2018 11:18:07    295000.0
28           NaN          NaN   01.08.2018 0:00:00    920671.0
29           NaN          NaN  09.08.2018 14:44:12    401200.0
30           NaN          NaN  21.08.2018 23:59:59    188800.0
31           NaN          NaN  21.08.2018 23:59:59    354000.0
32           NaN          NaN  17.09.2018 23:59:59   1613985.0
33           NaN          NaN                Всего   3773656.0

[34 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: ,у меня получилось, что два столбца(Дата и Сумма) встали рядом. А мне нужно, чтобы в "Дата Акта" добавилась ниже "Дата", а в "Сумма Акта" добавилась ниже "Сумма"

Comment: @Ireen1985, не понимаю что значит ниже... Можете привести в вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: добавила желаемый результат

Comment: супер!!!Большое спасибо!!!